# Conditional statement of 1 column to create another column with arithmatic functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to apply a conditional statement to the column "SETTLE" that will essentially create another column, titled "NEW_SETTLE". For entries that are <1000, i would want to multiple the SETTLE column by 10. However, the code below does not work.

```
#for settle prices < 1000, multiply it by 10
df_hg['NEW_SETTLE'] = df_hg.SETTLE.apply(
               lambda x: (df_hg.SETTLE * 10 if x < 1000 else df_hg.SETTLE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda is wrong. Try:

```
df_hg.SETTLE.apply(lambda x: (x * 10 if x < 1000 else x))
```